# Which LEGO boxes are compatible?

Tags: storage

TLG has produced a number of sets which come in reusable plastic boxes. I'm curious to know which of these are able to be easily stored together. Primarily, I'm wondering which boxes can be stacked, but if there are any that are compatible in other ways, that would be interesting, too.

As an example, these two boxes can be stacked on top of one another:

[image: 4626]
[image: 4625]

There are other variations, even in production currently, which aren't compatible with this style. For example:

[image: 10662]

I'd like to know which boxes are compatible with others.

Answer (score 3):

There has been a staggering amount of different size and shape LEGO buckets, tubs and boxes. A lot of them are stackable with each other (meaning the same size and shape box produced at the same time can be stacked). I think narowing down the question would be helpful. Are you looking for LEGO boxes currently in production? Or all boxes LEGO ever produced? I just did a quick search on Bricklink and over 300 results came up just for LEGO buckets (similar to the ones you are picturing above): http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&q=bucket&catLike=W It would be huge work to try to work out the compatibility of all of them.

Comment: I was hoping for a relatively complete list. I was assuming that there were a few basic styles which were all compatible and then a bunch of outliers. For example, looking through the Bricklink search you provided, it looks like there are a lot of containers which have 4 studs on top. I assume these are compatible, but I don't have any of them, so I have no idea if they actually fit together.

Comment: I see what you mean. Yeah, if the tubs were produced around the same time (you can check the date of production at Bricklink), you can safely assume they are compatible with the tubs that look similar in size and shape. If you still have doubts, I would suggest contacting the seller(s) who have them listed and ask them to make sure the tubs can nest together nicely. I don't know any other way to check. I have never seen a comprehensive list like that. Maybe it's time to make one. ;)